# How can I easily remove grass from a large area?

Tags: terraria

Sometimes I really need to remove undesired grass from mud or dirt.

There are many ways to plant grass (for example the [Staff of Regrowth](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Staff_Of_Regrowth)), but I don't know of a way to quickly *remove* it. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: I don't remember if Lava can burn off grass (and I can't test ATM), but it would be worth it to check it out.

Comment: Just curious, why do you want to remove the grass?

Comment: I have created platforms of dirt to farm blinkroot on it - but the grass happened to spread over my farm. Also, I have created artificial jungle - then I changed my mind and I want to farm glowing mushrooms in the area instead.

Comment: Make sure when you clear off the grass that you block the edges of the cleared area with something other than dirt so the grass doesn't just grow back. Alternately, put your farm up in the air a bit so it doesn't connect to the grass below, or build it underground.

Comment: http://img4.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20111018173510/minecraft/images/1/1e/TNT.png

Comment: Actually, that's what I did in the end... I just hoped not to rebuild all platforms myself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(1) As of 1.2.3, when you place blocks all around grass, the buried grass dies. You can use this mechanic by laying down something other than dirt to smother the grass, then mine your covering layer back off when you're done.

EDIT: This weekend I tried out laying down blocks to see if it's any better than just digging out the grass blocks. I found out that sand (and silt, and slush), if it falls, will NOT kill the grass it buries; you have to actually place the block in its final position to kill the grass.

(2) Doktoro Reichard suggested in a comment that lava will remove grass. Get several buckets (They stack now, so you don't have to use up more than one slot for 99 buckets), fill em with lava. Make sure to put up retaining walls around the area you want to clear. Then fill with lava, wait for the grass to die, and then scoop the lava back up. According to this [wiki article](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Lava), it kills grass and prevents grass growth within 2 blocks of the lava.

Comment: I have tested both strategies sucessfully as of v1.2.4.1. Though (1) doesn't seem much faster than hitting the blocks with pickaxe directly.

Answer (score 1):

I'm quite sure that Grass regrows on blocks in like a creeping effect, as such if you had a platform of land and just one block had grass somewhere on it it would grow back.

my only evidence is when i make sky gardens and i want grass blocks i make a small basin out of stones like this

|_______________|

and then i fill it with dirt even if i'm underground for a long time mining more cobblestone to make into stone blocks no grass will grow, i need grass seed to make a small patch and then it creeps along while i'm away.

If you use a pickax to remove the grass block and then block off the cleared land with something grass can't grow on like stone that should prevent it growing back.

of cause this only prevents it from growing back, removing it quickly is another thing which i know not of a way to do but i assume your problem is that you have to keep removing grass blocks and they keep coming back and your asking for a way to remove them quicker so prevent their grow back might help you

Answer (score 1):

Just hit the grass once with a "bad" pickaxe and the grass disappears. Using a bad one should prevent you from needing to replace blocks that you mined accidentally, speeding up the whole process.